# How to run Shoutem React Native apps locally for testing?

Tags: react-native, shoutem

I've been really enjoying using the Shoutem builder to create a starter template for React Native. However I want to use my own IDE (Deco IDE) to run a simulator locally and change the code.

However, after I "pull" my app from Shoutem via the CLI and run `NPM install + react-native link` the application won't compile for the simulator. If I use the command `shoutem run` the application will build and run perfectly, but this is not as convenient as having a simulator and being able to see the code as I change it.

Any help getting a shoutem app running locally in an simulator?

For anyone interested the error I am getting is: `Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist`

Comment: What's the command Deco use to start the application?

Comment: If I am not mistaken Deco uses `react-native run-ios`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to run Shoutem app locally.

One way is the `shoutem run` command. It is designed to work with Shoutem Preview application which you can download from the [Google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shoutem.extensions.preview&hl=en) or the [App store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shoutem-preview/id1211732978?mt=8). It can be reloaded to see the changes you've made to the local code. This command bundles only the JS code using the packager. Doesn't build native.

Beside `shoutem run` there are `shoutem run-ios` and `shoutem run-android` commands to build and run an RN project for the platform you've chosen. This way you get fully functional RN application which can be debugged as any other RN app. Both the JS code and native are built.

Do not forget to link extensions you're working on by using `shoutem link`.